# How i can setup sub domain to when ping sub domain get another ip

Tags: redirect, dns, ip

Hello i register in https://noip.com and gets me a domain http://test.no-ip.biz  this site every time my dynamic ip changed updated and i can know my ip any time when ping (test.no-ip.biz).
Now i want instead of (test.no-ip.biz) use my sub domain sub.domain.com i setup my domain to redirect to (test.no-ip.biz) and its work but when ping my domain get the ip of my host server. how i can setup sub domain to get the ip of (test.no-ip.biz)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a CNAME record in your domain which points to test.no-ip.biz:

in your domain definition add:

sub IN CNAME test.no-ip.biz.

Comment: Thank you i add record cname test.no-ip.biz to office.domain.com and it redirected to test.no-ip.biz but when ping office.domain.com it gets the ip of my host server, my application needs to get ip of test.no-ip.biz till work.

Comment: that's strange...some nameserver might cached the old record...try `dig +trace sub.domain.com` check if it resolves correctly; you can check with `dig sub.domain.com` for how long the entry will be cached